# ETH pending transaction (>4 days)

Tags: pending-transactions, bridge

I have a transaction pending on ETH which is bridging ETH to Linea Mainnet. I accidentally set my "advanced" to both Base and Priority to 10. Which now causing my transaction stuck more than 4 days since then.

I have my account on 2 browser which is Bing and Google. I bridge ETH through Bing extension. Now, the problem is I can't either cancel or speed up through my browser extension (Bing), then Google extension didn't pop the "pending" transaction...

Txn Hash here:
0x82ecbd1c812fd08190489bc8d1180f2341766dc4e7bcad829c5b5cb8d10627fb

Question:

1. Why is this happening(can't do any operation on browser extension)?
2. Will it stuck forever at there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's happening is that the gas price is too low and validators don't want to pick up the transaction.

Currently the gas prices are around 18 gWei. Your transaction is at 10. So, if prices come down, your transaction may still get included soon. Or not.

In reality, if the transaction's gas price is way too low, nodes will simply drop it at some point, since it makes no sense to keep your transaction around if it looks like it won't get processed any time soon. But this depends on each node's settings and priorities, so impossible to predict.

You can always bypass/cancel the transaction by sending a new transaction with the same nonce and higher gas price. Whether your used wallet shows this option or not, depends on the wallet and we can't really help you with that. However, it should be possible to manually select the used nonce for a transaction, through some sort of advanced settings. The nonce for that transaction is `0`.

Comment: Ok, it pass through after 7 days! Thanks for your answer!